# tf.get_variable doesn't accept Tensors for shape

Tags: tensorflow

It appears that `tf.get_variable` doesn't accept a `Tensor` for shape, only `int`. This is unlike `tf.Variable` which can accept `Tensors`. Is this correct, and if so, is there a workaround for getting `tf.get_variable` to work when the shape is a `Tensor`? I do not want to run `session` at this stage of graph construction, as it would complicate many things downstream.

I'm trying to use the cuDNN bindings for RNNs, which involves calling `params_size()` on a model created using `CudnnLSTM`. This returns the numbers of parameters to hold in the parameter buffer as a `Tensor`, which is then used to create the variable that holds the parameters. Instead of using `tf.Variable`, with its all caveats, I'd like to use `tf.get_variable` to hold the parameter values, so that I can easily initialize them using all the various initializers compatible with `tf.get_variable`, etc. All the new machinery is built around `tf.get_variable`, and so having to go back to the low-level `tf.Variable` is very cumbersome. It seems like a very strange limitation of `tf.get_variable` to not accept `Tensors` when `tf.Variable` does.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to provide an initializer that has a shape, but a dynamic one. For example, rather than

```
s = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=())
init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
tf.get_variable('foo', shape=(s,), initializer=init) # error, shape cannot be a Tensor
```

you would use

```
s = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=())
init = tf.random_normal((s,))
tf.get_variable('foo', initializer=init, validate_shape=False)
```

Note however that initialization of the variable is now tricky. Calling `tf.global_variables_initializer()` will attempt to initialize `'foo'`, so you need to make sure that either it can be initialized (feeding some values if necessary) or handle initialization yourself.

Another workaround is to initialize your variable to any value (say a scalar of zero) and later `tf.assign` a value with the desired shape to it when the shape is known. It is a bit easier to work with during initialization since the initial value is discarded after the fir `assign`, so it can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like

```
input = tf.constant([[1,2,3]])
dim = input.get_shape()[1]
w = tf.get_variable('foo', shape=(dim, dim))
```